# multiprocessing in python runs all the jobs at the same time

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have a function that I want to call 100 times with different input values. I have 8 processors and I want 8 jobs to run simultaneously and after one is finished the other one to start. However, in my script below, python starts all jobs at the same time, what needs to be changed?

```
global bits
bits = np.zeros(100)

def _multi(bits,idd,some_function):
    bits[idd] = some_function(idd)

jobs = []
for i in range(100):
    d = multiprocessing.Process(target=_multi,args=(bits,i,some_function))
    jobs.append(d)
    d.start()
for job in jobs:
    job.join()
```

Comment: You might want to use a Pool: https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/multiprocessing.html?highlight=process#multiprocessing.pool.Pool

Comment: You shouldn't be starting more processes than theoretical cores anyway; do you have 101 CPU cores?

Comment: @roganjosh - I beg to differ. There are many use cases for running more processes than one has cores. My desktop Linux machine has about 300 processes at the moment, but I assure you that I don't have 300 cores.

Comment: @Robᵩ If you had a CPU-bound task, would you launch 300 processes? If the task isn't CPU-bound, what is the point in `multiprocessing`?

Answer (score 1):

use pool to set the processes.

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import operator
import os

def process(func,arg):
    pool = mp.Pool(processes=8)

    results=[pool.apply_async(func, args=(arg,i)) for i in range(100)]
    r=[]
    for p in results:
        try:
            r.append(p.get())
        except Exception:
            print("error getting process: %s" % os.getpid())
    return r
```